# Automating an SSRS 2008 R2 Report Snapshots and run report with most recent data

Tags: ssrs, reporting, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I would like to automate a report snapshot, but there is only an option to take a snapshot in the Report History Tab. All the resources I've found suggest I need to go to processing options and select "Render this report from a snapshot". But I don't want to do that - when I go to a report, I want to get the most recent data. However daily at midnight I'd like to take a snapshot and store it in the history in case I want to compare the reports as of midnight for the last few weeks.

Or am I doing this wrong and have to create a subscription instead?

Note: this is for an auditing database and has way to much data in to query a range with more than 1 day in it - reports are restricted as such. (1 day has over 1 million rows on it's own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS snapshots will not give you the functionality you are looking for.

You can create a SSRS subscription that will output an excel file (or another file type) to a file share.  You can take the query from your reports and use that to copy point in time data to another database/table (using a night job).

The easiest solution would probably be the subscription though.

HTH, 
Dan

Comment: I thought as much. Ideally I want an image of the report generated daily and stored on the server. Do you know any good tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any tutorials.  However, it's pretty simple to set up.  In your report just go to the subscription tab.  When you are in the Subscription set up screen, you'll need to change the "Delivered by:" option to "Windows File Share".  The rest of the fields are pretty self explanatory.  You will need to enter the credentials (domain account) used to write to the particular file share folder.  Finally set up the date and times you want to run the subscriptions.  Finally set any parameters if the report has them.  Let me know if you have any additional questions.